# Can Envers identify who the modifier is?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I want to be able to track the responsible for eventual changes in the data.

Do I have to do this by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a @RevisionEntity and a RevisionListener.
There is an example for a similar scenarion in http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/#revisionlog